# How do I beep in Kubuntu, using Java?

Tags: java, ubuntu

I've been a fan of Ubuntu for some time. For the past year or so I've only run XUbuntu on my laptop, I caught a glimpse of Kubuntu and had to try it. Up until I tried to make a simple application it was awesome.

How do I make the computer beep? `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep()`, `getToolkit().beep()` and `System.out.print("07")` do not work in Kubuntu. I don't want to stream audio all day long, I just want a short beep. Is it even possible?

Comment: Are you muted, mate? Look in your mixer (alsamixer?)

Comment: Haha no I am not, but that is an excellent question. I'm actually quite familiar with digital sound, I've had a home studio for a decade or so and yes I did change everything out to make sure it wasn't the equipment, unless its internal in the computer but I doubt it because I'm not the first to have this problem and despite it being all over google I haven't been able to find a solid solution. So ts much more likely this is some sort of KDE issue or something of that nature.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to make the beep work, however on XUbuntu I am able to load a click sound file and use that that in its place without any external libraries. So that's good enough for my purposes but it has not worked on Kubuntu. In other words, I don't have an answer but I'm moving on. I left this unanswered because I'm still interested in understanding the initial issue and possibly fixing it if anyone happens to know anything about what the cause is.